# Django FileUpload choice inside of a dropdown (ModelChoiceField)

Tags: python, django, web

Hi is it possible to put a choice inside of a dropdown and when it is clicked it will allow user to upload file, right now I have a dynamic dropdown built using ModelChoiceField but I want to add a choice that will allow the user to upload the file if they don't want to choose to use the default choices.

Something like the one in the picture but when the '------------' choice is clicked it will pop up something that will allow user to upload file.

[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxqHc.png)

I've been looking for the answer but couldn't find one unfortunately. thanks.

This is the models.py

```
class DefaultNetwork(models.Model):
    source = models.FileField(max_length=300, upload_to="api/default-network")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.source.delete()
        super(DefaultNetwork, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

This is the forms.py

```
class DefaultNetworkForm(forms.ModelForm):
    default_network = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=DefaultNetwork.objects.all(), label="Default Network")

    class Meta:
        model = DefaultNetwork
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Answerers would really appreciate it if you added any code you've tried to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @baranskistad Hi thank you for the reply, I've added the code

Comment: You could subclass `ModelChoiceField` in order to add a choice ('other...' for example) to the list in the `__init__` method of ModelChoiceField. Then in your template, you would need javascript to unhide a form to create a new DefaultNetwork when user selects 'other...' and the user could then upload the file. But from a UI perspective, why not just let the user choose existing or upload a new one next to each other?